# eth.getBalance(<account>, <block>) returns "Error: missing trie node"

Tags: balances, state-trie

I have used `--gcmode=archive` to download all the state tries and `eth.syncing` returns `false` meaning my node is in sync. When I execute `eth.getBalance` for blocks closer to the current block I obtain the correct value but for older blocks I get `"Error: missing trie node"`. Is there any other way of obtaining balance of an account in all the blocks from the genesis block?

Comment: Are you doing it for the main net? With which `--syncmode` did you launch it?

Comment: I did not put anything. I think it will be default then. I am working with main net.

Answer (score 1):

You must have launched with `--syncmode fast --gcmode archive`. If you did not say any `--syncmode`, then it was `fast`.

The `fast` mode means that it downloads a full state at a recent block, say `n`. Then it computes all new states, for blocks `n + m` from this full state. `archive` means that it will **not** discard *old* states, like `n`, `n+1` as it advances. But it still does **not** have any state prior to `n`.

Which means that:

- you can query `.getBalance(me, n)` and `me, n + m`.
- you can **not** query `.getBalance(me, 0)` to `me, n - 1`.

If you want to have all states, including prior to the time you launched it, you have to delete your chain data and restart it with `-syncmode full --gcmode archive`.

I hope you have a good SSD...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I followed the documentation here - https://blog.ethereum.org/2018/02/14/geth-1-8-iceberg%C2%B9/ .. It says that - Trie pruning is enabled on all --syncmode variations (including --syncmode=full). If you are running an archive node where you would like to retain all historical data, you should disable pruning via --gcmode=archive. Anyways I will try with --syncmode full as well.

Comment: Yes, pruning means "removing what exists". What you need is to disable pruning, plus a way to recreate the missing ones -> syncmode